# How to shade text in latex without a box?

Tags: backgrounds, shading

I would like to add a background shade to my text in a report. I do not want to use a box to wrap the text though. Is this possible? MWE of my code is given below. In the code, I would like to shade the description list.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}

This document contains the author's responses to the comments from Examiner 2 and Examiner 3.\\\\ 
\Large{\underline{Response Categories}}
\begin{description}
  \item[A (Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.
  \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had been placed.
  \item[P (Partially Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.
  \item[R (Reject)] Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.
  \item[RM (Reject with Suitable Modifications to Text)] Denotes that author does not accept the broader implication of the comment, but the text has been modified to address individual points raised as part of the comment, as applicable.
\end{description}
```

Comment: for (la)TeX almost every thing is a box.

Comment: @touhami: I think the O.P. referred to something like `\colorbox`  or `mdframed` etc, not the real `\box` register, but I may be wrong, of course.

Comment: What do you want to shade exactly, in this code?

Comment: @Bernard I want to shade the description list without inserting it inside a box.

Comment: That's your second question with some missing code. In the other the \begin{description} was lost, here the \end{document}. Beside this: I would use tcolorbox.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, `tcolorbox` was my idea too, but the O.P. does not want a box ;-)

Comment: Well, it is not inserted in a box, it's inserted in an environment (of course there is ultimately a box behind the scene, but all TeX is about boxes). I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: The OP doesn't want a box "to wrap the text". So imho the main point are linebreaks and perhaps pagebreaks and both works fine with tcolorbox.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Right. I've added a primitive `tcolorbox` answer

Answer (score 4):

Using `tcolorbox`, shaded background is not really difficult, for example using `interior style={top color=red,bottom color=yellow}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

This document contains the author's responses to the comments from Examiner 2 and Examiner 3.\\\\ 
\Large{\underline{Response Categories}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,enhanced,interior style={top color={red},bottom color={yellow}}]
  \begin{description}
  \item[A (Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.
  \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had been placed.
  \item[P (Partially Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.
  \item[R (Reject)] Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.
  \item[RM (Reject with Suitable Modifications to Text)] Denotes that author does not accept the broader implication of the comment, but the text has been modified to address individual points raised as part of the comment, as applicable.
  \end{description}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is perhaps to use the `framed` package, which defines a `shaded`(the shade overflows the margins) and a `shaded*`(the shade fits the margins) environments. These environments can break across pages. B.t.w., one of your description texts  flows into the margin with the default layout. If you don't use margin notes, you can load the `geometry` package, which sets more sensible margins. Alternatively, you can load `enumitem` and use the `nextline` description style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush3}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This document contains the author's responses to the comments from Examiner 2 and Examiner 3.\\\\
\Large{\underline{Response Categories}}
\begin{shaded}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item[A (Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.
  \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had been placed.
  \item[P (Partially Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.
  \item[R (Reject)] Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.
  \item[RM (Reject with Suitable Modifications to Text)] Denotes that author does not accept the broader implication of the comment, but the text has been modified to address individual points raised as part of the comment, as applicable.
\end{description}
\end{shaded}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Thistle3!50}
\begin{shaded*}
\begin{description}
  \item[A (Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.
  \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had been placed.
  \item[P (Partially Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.
  \item[R (Reject)] Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.
  \item[RM (Reject with Suitable Modifications to Text)] Denotes that author does not accept the broader implication of the comment, but the text has been modified to address individual points raised as part of the comment, as applicable.
\end{description}
\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option. May be one can do better using the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.8,.95,1}
\definecolor{LightBlue}{rgb}{.8,.9,1}
\sethlcolor{lightblue}

\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries
                                \sethlcolor{LightBlue}\hl{#1}}

   % to be automatic                             
\newcommand{\bgitem}[2]{\item[#1]\hl{#2}}

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
  \item[A (Accept)]\hl{Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.}
  \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)]\hl{Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had been placed.}
  \item[P (Partially Accept)]\hl{Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.}
  % here with \bgitem
  \bgitem{R (Reject)}{Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

It is better if one define a newenvironment `hldescription` and make the change to label local.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

This document contains the author's responses to the comments from Examiner 2 and 
Examiner 3.

\bigskip\noindent
{\Large\underline{Response Categories}\par}\smallskip
\noindent
\colorbox{blue!40!white!80}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{description}
        \item[A (Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts the comments in their entirety.
        \item[AM (Accept with Modifications to Original Context)] Denotes that the author 
        accepts the comments in their entirety, and changes to the thesis would involve 
        modification to the original context in which the relevant subject matter had 
        been placed.
        \item[P (Partially Accept)] Denotes that the author accepts certain aspects of 
        the comments while explicating reservations on the rest.
        \item[R (Reject)] Denotes that the author does not accept the comments.
        \item[RM (Reject with Suitable Modifications to Text)] Denotes that author does 
        not accept the broader implication of the comment, but the text has been modified 
        to address individual points raised as part of the comment, as applicable.
    \end{description}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]