# How to bold only a single character in a word?

Tags: pdftex

I have a description list that looks like follows (MWE):

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Author's Action (\textbf{A}ccomplished or \textbf{P}roposed)] \textbf{A}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Here what I would like to do is to only bold the first letter of the words Accomplished and Proposed. Using the method shown in MWE, I see that the entire word is rendered in bold. Is there a way to only bold the first character of each word?

Comment: remove `\bfseries` from `\descriptionlabel` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284543/71471

Comment: Your example above is incomplete, but your text is in the argument of description which is already bold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1:** use `format=\normalfont` from `enumitem` package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[format=\normalfont]
\item[Author's Action (\textbf{A}ccomplished or \textbf{P}roposed)] \textbf{A}\\ 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

**or 2:**  redefine `\descriptionlabel`

```
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont #1}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the default *description* lists, items are shown in bold.

To avoid this, use `\mdseries`:

```
\item[\mdseries Author's Action (\textbf{A}ccomplished or \textbf{P}roposed)] \textbf{A}\\
```

If you need this for the whole document, you may define a macro

```
\newcommand{\ITEM}[1]{\item[\mdseries #1]}
```

and use it as follows

```
\ITEM{Author's Action (\textbf{A}ccomplished or \textbf{P}roposed)} \textbf{A}\\
```

Or you can just redefine `\descriptionlabel`:

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{{\mdseries #1}}
```

and keep the original syntax.